# iOS/Objective C image alpha low when I goes out of bounds of parent image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image editing iOS app.

I have a T-shirt(parent image) image as background image and I can add other image(sub images) into T-shirt image.

When I scale, move, rotate the sub images meanwhile if portion of image going out of bounds of parent image then that portion should be low its alpha value.

Similarly I’ve shown in screenshot.

[image: here is the screenshot]

I’ve wrote the following code.

```
UIImageView* randomView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.imageView.bounds];

    randomView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    randomView.alpha = 0.8;
    randomView.image = image; // 'image' coming from gallery or camera

    UIImageView *maskView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.imageView.image];
    [maskView setFrame:self.imageView.bounds];
    self.imageView.layer.mask = maskView.layer;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more imageView (copy of main image with alpha) behind the T-shirt view.

Comment: I did this practice but not succeeded, would you please elaborate with some sort of code.

Comment: you need to mask you T-shirt image too - to get transparent background behind it and make new image visible.